# iCloud one time setup not taking place

Tags: ios, installation, icloud

I have an app that runs on OS X and iOS, using iCloud.
Quite often, from a fresh iOS install, the one-time setup is not taking place. In clear, I don't receive the StoreWillChange/StoreDidChange events.
App is working otherwise fine, and synchs data OK.
But as I am running my deduplication upon receiving the StoreDidChange event, that's kind of annoying.

Do you know why - or under which condition - the one-time setup does not take place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that anyway, the de-duplication algorithm need to be run more often than just upon reception of StoreDidChange event.
So that kills the question itself.